# BackProjection image is black

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image, opencv, image-processing

Please have a look at the below code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat image,image_clone,testImage,testImageHSV,imageHSV,testImageHue,imageHue;

int ch[] = {0,0};
int bins=10;

char *windowName = "BackProjection";

void histAndBackProjection(int,void*);

int main()
{
    //Load the image
    image = imread("E:/Trip/DSC01894.jpg");
    image_clone ;

    image.copyTo(image_clone);

    //Break a small piece from the image
    testImage = image(Rect(450,470,20,20));
    cv::rectangle(image_clone,Point(450,470),Point(500,500),Scalar(255,0,0),2);

    //Transfor to HSV
    cvtColor(testImage,testImageHSV,CV_BGR2HSV);
    cvtColor(image,imageHSV,CV_BGR2HSV);

    //Seperate the HUE channel
    testImageHue.create(testImageHSV.size(),testImageHSV.depth());
    imageHue.create(imageHSV.size(),imageHSV.depth());

    cv::mixChannels(&testImageHSV,1,&testImageHue,1,ch,1);
    cv::mixChannels(&imageHSV,1,&imageHue,1,ch,1);


    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image",image_clone);

    namedWindow("Test Image");
    imshow("Test Image",testImage);

    //Creating windows for trackbar
    namedWindow(windowName);

    //Creating the track bar
    createTrackbar("Select Bins",windowName,&bins,255,histAndBackProjection);

    histAndBackProjection(0,0);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

void histAndBackProjection(int, void *)
{
    MatND histImage,backProjection;

    int histSize = MAX(bins,2);
    float range[]={0,180};
    const float* rangePtr={range};

    //Calculate the histogram
    cv::calcHist(&testImageHue,1,0,Mat(),histImage,1,&histSize,&rangePtr,true,false);
    cv::normalize(histImage,histImage,1.0);

    //Do the backprojection
    cv::calcBackProject(&imageHue,1,0,histImage,backProjection,&rangePtr,1,true);

    imshow(windowName,backProjection);
}
```

I am using this code for backprojection. However, my backprojected output is 100% black! No matter to where I move the slider, it is still black! In my image, I am targeted to backproject a 100% white location, because I need to find white areas.

Why is this? Any issue in code?

Comment: before you downvote, make sure to comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you [normalize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?#normalize) your histogram:

```
cv::normalize(histImage,histImage,1.0);
```

will scale all elements of the histogram so that their L2 norm is `1.0`. However, you attempt backprojection:

```
cv::calcBackProject(&imageHue,1,0,histImage,backProjection,&rangePtr,1,true);
```

with a scale of `1`. The output is of type `CV_8UC1`, so values less than `1` (which is *all of them*) get truncated to zero.

Instead, you should normalize the histogram in this manner:

```
cv::normalize(histImage, histImage, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
```

Or change the `scale` parameter in `cv::calcBackProject()` to `255`. It should be noted that these two approaches give different (though roughly similar) results. Using `NORM_MINMAX` seems to be more popular in histogram usages.